# How get propery value of an dynamic type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic, anonymous-types, iqueryable

**[update]**

> I'm sorry, i should tag this question
>   as MVC-2, I pass result of query into
>   view's model, so i must specify type
>   of my model in View's header
>   defintion. I declare it like this:
>
> `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IQueryable<dynamic>>"`
>
> how ever nothing changed and none of
>   answers doesn't work for me :(.
>   finally i used an ModelView class as
>   helper to put my query result in it.
>   :(

**[/update]**

I have a query like this:

```
IQueryable<dynamic> result = from d in KiaNetRepository.KiaNetEntities.Discounts
             where d.AgentTypeID == agentTypeId
             select new { d.Category,  d.DiscountValue, d.PriceConfige };
```

then i retrive value in my view like this:

```
foreach(var item in result){

    Category cat = item.Category; // throws exception 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Category' 

    //...

}
```

note that type of query as IQueryable is anonymouse class...

Comment: Try to exprole `item` indebuger, I think you will find the answer there

Comment: Debugger shows that `item` contains `{ d.Category,  d.DiscountValue, d.PriceConfige }` members!!! I got confused!

Comment: Do you need `IQueryable<dynamic>`? Can't you just use the word `IQueryable`. Having it as `dynamic` will remove your IntelliSense as dynamic types are designed for late binding. This would also help you solve your problem as to why the `Category` object is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare names explicitly:

```
select new { Category = d.Category,  DiscountValue = d.DiscountValue, PriceConfige = d.PriceConfige }
```

Comment: +1 yep - I think the OP's code is declaring an array otherwise.

Comment: It won't change anything, it's compiled to the exact same IL

Comment: no, this is exactly the same. The property names do not have to be explicit if there is no ambiquity. `new` without a type name always creates an anonymous class, never an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not forcing result to be of `IQueryeable<dynamic>` for any specific reason, I would recommend using `var result = ...`. This will let the compiler make `result` of type `IQueryable<T>` with `T` the type of the anonymous class that you create using `new { ... }` in the select. There is no necessity for using `dynamic` from the code that you show here.

Comment: If you removed `dynamic` and it is still throwing this exception during runtime, you have not recompiled. Such errors are given compile-time if the object is not dynamic.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your answer but you can't expose `var`s outside of the class, so that won't work. `dynamic` should work here but for some reason it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the inappropriate declaration `IQueryable<dynamic>` by `var`, sure it works, I've just also tested it.

Comment: @Jalal Why downvoting everybody ? Daniel and I tested and found it working. The problem is not necessarily with our answers which are accurate but maybe with your misunderstanding or bad application of it ? Or if we definitely are wrong (which is of course possible), please explain why, put your code updated according to our answers, show where it doesn't work and what's the message. Once again both of us tested and have it work. Rather strange, no ?

Comment: Finally i found another solution, i create a ModelView class and pass data to view through that,
And thank all you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `foreach` loop being in the view page gets compiled into a separate assembly. Since anonymous types are internal the dynamic doesn't see it because of the permissions don't allow it.

Simplest fix is to call `ToList()` on your query statement and then select each anonymous type and copy parameters to a declared class or expandoobject.